# Link only underlines when hovering href

Tags: html, css, navigation, hover, nav

I honestly wasn't sure how to word the title, but if you look at the example you'll see what I'm talking about. I want the underline to change colors when the list item is hovered, not just when the href is hovered.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/wsa9f/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="main-nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Nav Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Nav Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Nav Item 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#main-nav {
    background-color: #990000;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#990000), to(#8b0000)); /* Chrome, Safari 4+ */
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #990000, #8b0000); /* Chrome 10-25, iOS 5+, Safari 5.1+ */
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #990000, #8b0000); /* Firefox 3.6-15 */
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #990000, #8b0000); /* Opera 11.10-12.00 */
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #990000, #8b0000); /* Chrome 26, Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera 12.10+ */
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    height: 45px;
    width: 100%;
}
#main-nav li {
    border-right: 1px solid #9f4f49;
    color: #ffffff;
    float: left;
    font-family:'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.6em;
    font-weight: 300;
    height: 15px;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 8px 24px 22px 24px;
    text-align: center;
}
#main-nav li#iu-degrees-link {
    width: 181px;
}
#main-nav li#iupui-degrees-link {
    width: 108px;
}
#main-nav li#research-link {
    width: 80px;
}
#main-nav li:focus, #main-nav li:hover {
    background-color: #bd0202;
}
#main-nav a {
    border-bottom: 4px solid #ffffff;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
#main-nav a:focus, #main-nav a:hover {
    border-color: #91d6bd;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that you want everything the same, but apply the green color when hover on `li` parent. In this case you want to select the `li` hover in CSS and apply to child `a`. See **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/acarlon/wsa9f/3/)**. Relavant code change is:

```
 #main-nav li:hover a{
     border-color: #91d6bd;
     text-decoration: none;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here: http://jsfiddle.net/wsa9f/1/

You were creating the border on the normal state and changing it on hover.

I removed the creation of the border and moved it to the hover state.

```
        #main - nav a {
            color: #ffffff;
            padding - bottom: 5px;
        }

        #main - nav a: focus,
        #main - nav a: hover {
            border - bottom: 4px solid #91d6bd;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
```

Comment: I need the white underlines off hover, but have the underline change colors whenever you hover over the "button", not just the link

Comment: Oh sorry @ansarob I miss-read your question. Add the `:hover` state to the list item. That should do it. I'll update my answer once I have a moment.

Answer (score -1):

```
#main-nav a {
    border-bottom: 4px solid #ffffff;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#main-nav li a:focus,
#main-nav li:hover a {
    border-color: #91d6bd;
}
```